# WP8 emulator fails to start (Hyper-V issue)

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, emulation, rdp, hyper-v

EDIT: **SOLVED**

I have issue that causes WP8 emulator to not work. When I start the emulator I get this:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.Xde.Client.RdpClientInterop.IMsRdpClientNonScriptable3.set_NegotiateSecurityLayer(Boolean pfNegotiate)
   at Microsoft.Xde.Client.DisplayForm.SetSecureModeOn()
   at Microsoft.Xde.Client.DisplayForm.InitClientSettings()
   at Microsoft.Xde.Client.DisplayForm..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Xde.Client.EmulatorForm.InitDisplayForm()
   at Microsoft.Xde.Client.EmulatorForm.OnActivated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Active(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmActivate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at Microsoft.Xde.Client.SkinnedForm.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Basically it looks like it can't connect to the virtual machine. I can start the WP8 image using Hyper-V Manager just fine but when I click "Connect..." it doesn't do anything. I believe this is was causes the emulator to fail. I've tried re-installing Hyper-V but that doesn't seem to do the trick. It looks like the issue is RDP related. Any ideas how to get this sorted out? I can't do anything before I get this fixed. OS is obviously W8 Pro x64, CPU is i7 3770K (virtualisation stuff enabled) and ASUS P8Z77-V (using the integrated intel nic).

I can start it but the "Connect..." doesn't do anything. This basically means that I can't interact with any virtual machine either that I create using Hyper-V manager.
http://abload.de/img/hyperv7rirw.png

Comment: Just some other things to try... 1. Ensure USB 3.0 is disabled in BIOS. 2. Open command prompt as admin and enter 'bcedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto' and then 'bcedit /enum' to test if it worked.  Just some things I had to do when I ran into problems with it... Hope it helps.

Comment: The solution in this thread solved my issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/528d6ca2-78bd-4ca7-9279-3f75c4f5a19d/xde-crashing-on-startup

Phew! Feeeeeels gooooood now! This was major pain...